# Hide Navigation Bar Prism Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, prism

I have  the following set in my view code behind

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

and I have it also in the XAML

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

However the navigation panel is still displaying when navigating with Prism and the follow code:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/RecipeListPage");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating with the absolute method such as:

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync(new System.Uri("http://www.RecipeDatabase/RecipeListPage", System.UriKind.Absolute));
```

Fixes this issue. Not sure why its needed. Also hiding with just the XAML code as well is sufficient.

Enjoy.